# yii2 Failed to instantiate component or class

Tags: php, yii2

First time I use yii2 I  tried to call an API postCanada.
inside my module I have this point

```
  use common\modules\OrderShipping\APIPostCanada\PostCanada as API;
  $API = \Yii::createObject(API::class);
```

I can see my function inside my API for example

```
   $API->canadaPostOrigin();
```

but on my catalog (frontpage)  I have this error, I do not understand.

my api postCanada class

```
  namespace common\modules\OrderShipping\APIPostCanada;

  class postCanada
  {
  .....
  }
```

What is the action to resolve this point.

Thank you

There the error

```
    /home/www/oscv4_b2/lib/frontend/controllers/IndexController.php:272:
object(yii\di\NotInstantiableException)[251]
  protected 'message' => string 'Failed to instantiate component or class "common\modules\OrderShipping\APIPostCanada\PostCanada".' (length=97)
  private string 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 0
  protected string 'file' => string '/home/www/oscv4_b2/lib/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php' (length=59)
  protected int 'line' => int 510
  private array 'trace' (Exception) => 
    array (size=18)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'file' => string '/home/www/oscv4_b2/lib/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php' (length=59)
          'line' => int 386
          'function' => string 'getDependencies' (length=15)
          'class' => string 'yii\di\Container' (length=16)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
```

...

```
ReflectionException: Class "common\modules\OrderShipping\APIPostCanada\PostCanada" does not exist in /home/www/oscv4_b2/lib/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php on line <i>508</i>
```

and

```
yii\di\NotInstantiableException: Failed to instantiate component or class "common\modules\OrderShipping\APIPostCanada\PostCanada". in /home/www/oscv4_b2/lib/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php on line <i>510</i>
```

Comment: may be class name issue, See `class postCanada` and `PostCandada as API`

Comment: Yes exact, thank you